# Encontre a primeira linha na matriz com todos os elementos positivos, e a soma desses elementos. Reduzir todos os elementos para essa soma

Tags: python

Encontre a primeira linha na matriz com todos os elementos positivos, e a soma desses elementos. Reduzir todos os elementos para essa soma.

Aqui é a minha tentativa, mas desta forma somar os elementos positivos:

```
matrix = [[-5, -6, 2], [7, 2, 3], [8, 4, -9]]

summ = 0
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    pos = False
    for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
        if matrix[i][j] > 0:
            pos = True
            summ += matrix[i][j]

if pos:
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
            matrix[i][j] = summ
    print("Sum of the row with all positive elements: ", summ)
    for i in matrix:
        print(" ",i)

else:
    print("There is not a row with all positive elements.")
```

Comment: Não entendi bem qual a sua dúvida, poderia escrever com suas palavras? Qual erro está dando no seu código?

Comment: Downvote porque é dever de casa.

Answer (score 0):

Isso resolve?

```
sum = 0;
pos = False;

for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
        if matrix[i][j] > 0:
           pos = True;
           sum+=matrix[i][j];
        else
           pos = False;
           sum = 0;
           break;
    if pos:
       break;

if pos:
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
            matrix[i][j] = sum;
    print('Sum of the row with all positive elements: ',sum);
    for i in matrix:
        print(' ',i);
else:
  print("There is not a row with all positive elements.");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> matrix = [[-5, -6, 2], [7, 2, 3], [8, 4, -9]]
>>> matrix
[[-5, -6, 2], [7, 2, 3], [8, 4, -9]]
>>> for line in matrix:
...  if not [i for i in line if i<0]:
...   soma = sum(line)
...   print 'Soma:',soma
...   print 'Linha:',line
...   matrix = [[soma for i in l] for l in matrix]
...   break
... 
Soma: 12
Linha: [7, 2, 3]
>>> matrix
[[12, 12, 12], [12, 12, 12], [12, 12, 12]]
```